# How to know if a char array has a null element in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, null, character-arrays

Say if I have : 
    `unsigned char* str = "k0kg"`

And 0 is the null element. When I loop through it using a for loop, how do I check if the array has a null?

I tried:
    `if (str[1]==0):`
I also tried:
    `if (str[1]=="0"):`

And they didn't work. :(

The loop:

```
for (i=0;i<num_bytes;i++){
    if (str[i]!=0){
        printf("null spotted\n");
}
```

Comment: `"0"` is character zero, aka ascii char 48 (0x30 hex). `0` is value zero, aka null/false

Comment: @MarcB to be 100% correct, you should use single quotes, not double.

Comment: @MarcB: To be correct *at all*, you should use single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

In C, strings, by definition, are terminated by '\0', the NUL character.  So all (valid) strings have a '\0' in them, at the end.

To find the position of the '\0', simply use strlen():

```
const char * const end = str + strlen(str);
```

It's odd that you are using "unsigned char" if you are dealing with normal, printable strings.  If you mean that you have a memory block with *bytes* it in and you want to find the first 0x00 byte, then you'll need a pointer to the start of the memory *and* the size of the memory area, in bytes.  Then, you'd use memchr():

```
// Where strSize is the number of bytes that str points to.
const unsigned char * const end = memchr(str, 0, strSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually looking for the null element then you should do the following condition :

```
if(str[i]=='\0')
```

Answer (score 1):

> Say if I have : unsigned char* str = "k0kg"
>
> And 0 is the null element. When I loop through it using a for loop, how do I check if the array has a null?

You're terminology is going to confuse any C programmer.  You're confusing character representations with values.  You're not looking for a null character ("null element", which would be `'\0'`), you're looking for the character `'0'`. So...

```
int len = strlen(str);
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if(str[i] == '0')
        printf("found it");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `strchr`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *str = "k0kg";
    char *p = strchr(str, '0');
    if(p){
        printf("find at %d\n", (int)(p - str));//find at 1
    }
    if(p=strchr(str, 0)){
        printf("find at %d\n", (int)(p - str));//find at 4
    }
    str = "k\0kg";
    if(p=strchr(str, 0)){
        printf("find at %d\n", (int)(p - str));//find at 1
    }

    return 0;
}
```